# How to find out in Eclipse if certain method is called from another method directly or indirectly?

Tags: java, eclipse

How to find out in Eclipse if certain method is potentially invoked or reachable (directly or indirectly) from another method?

Assume I want to refactor `A.one()` which can be negatively influenced by a side-effect in `D.four()`. Therefore I'd like to find out if `D.four()` can potentially be invoked from `A.one()`. I can see which methods are called from `A.one()` using the Call Hierarchy. I can navigate the call tree and eventually find that `A.one()` calls `B.two()` which calls `C.three()` which calls `D.four()`.

Is there a way in Eclipse to make this search somehow automatic?

ps. There's a "Filters..." option in Call Hierarchy Dialog, but it only hides matching names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a modified version of the way you (@lexicore) found, that involves significantly less button punching (my changes in **bold**):

- Open Call Hierarchy for A.one(), Show Callee Hierarchy.
- **Select the root node, and press the * key until the whole tree is expanded. Note that you only need to press * on the root node. This will expand the whole tree in "no time".**
- Right mouse click, Copy Expanded Hierarchy.
- Paste into a text file.
- Full-text search for D.four().

**Notes**

- The key * expands all unexpanded leaf nodes one level.
- The keys + and - works for expanding and closing just the selected node.
- I've tried this on a Swedish keyboard, where * is located in a different place than on a US keyboard, but hopefully Eclipse won't care about that.

**Update**

[Here is some documentation](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/call-hierarchy/usage.html), where the * key is mentioned.

Comment: `*`! Thanks! My colleagues asked me to thank you sincerely. :)

Comment: Great! I  just noticed that numpad * (It's called Numpad_Multiply in Eclipse) works too.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I can not find any documentation on these key bindings. When I go into Preferences->General->Keys, where "all" key bindings are defined, these keys are not bound to anything.

Comment: Here is some documentation, where the * key is mentioned: http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/call-hierarchy/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

We've just encountered a way. Not really "automatic", involves a lot of `->`-button punching. :)

- Open Call Hierarchy for `A.one()`, Show Callee Hierarchy.
- Start from the root, expand the whole tree by clicking the `->` button many many times. Really many times. :)
- Right mouse click, Copy Expanded Hierarchy.
- Paste into a text file.
- Full-text search for `D.four()`.

I hope there are better ways not involving punching the `->`-button.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I know of, is to navigate manually to `D.four()`, use the `Call Hierarchy` on that method and see if `A.one()` is contained in the hierarchy.

Comment: I'll need to manually search through the whole hierarchy to do this. A bit hard it the tree is large.