# How can I determine if a particular Java method calls another particular Java method several stack levels down?

Tags: java, methods

So let's say that I have method A and I want to know if kicking off method A could possibly result in method D being kicked off.  It's obviously easy to determine if A calls D directly, but is there a way to determine if D is called further down the stack (ex: A calls B, B calls C, C calls D)?

Basically I'm looking to do a recursive search of all method calls with in a particular method to find another specific method call.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Brandon

Comment: Programmatically, or in your IDE?

Comment: Any code you want to show us?

Comment: In the IDE.  Unfortunately I don't have an easy way to run these methods, and even if I did it would take a lot of work to be sure that my testing ran through every possible conditional branch in the code.  I was hoping for some kind of tool that I could plug method A into and determine if there is a path to method D.

As for code to show, that's the big problem: I've got hundreds of classes and hundreds more methods, the complexity is why it's unrealistic to sift through each branch by hand.

Comment: I would accept a programmatic solution as well at this point, I just figured there would be a tool somewhere with this functionality already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out in Eclipse if certain method is called from another method directly or indirectly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715356/how-to-find-out-in-eclipse-if-certain-method-is-called-from-another-method-direc)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDE (like Eclipse or Netbeans), you could put a breakpoint in method D, and then have a look at the stack at that point in the Debug view.

In Eclipse for example, there will be a panel that looks something like this:

[image]

<sup>Image from [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-debug_view.htm)</sup>

You can see in the stack that `main()` has been called.

In your example it might look something like this:

```
ClassZ.D() line: P
ClassY.C() line: O
ClassX.B() line: N
ClassW.A() line: M
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this search without actually running the code.  I need to know if there is any possible branch in the conditionals that will get me from A to D.  And there are so many classes and methods interconnected that doing that analysis by hand isn't realistic.

Comment: @BrandonToms, see Raedwald's answer for how to do this without running the code.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is a kind of "Dijkstra's algorithm" for finding the shortest path from point A (aka, "method A") to point B (aka, "method B").  I'd like to give two parameters to some tool, method A and method B, and have it spit out the shortest path from A to B.  Because of the complexity of the interconnected classes, this is the only way I'm going to be able to determine if A will ever call B.

Comment: and if the code uses reflection somewhere then it will be a very difficult task...

Answer (score 0):

[Found the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715643/3297929)!  Apparently I wasn't the only one that came up with this question, I just didn't word it quite the same.  Here's the best solution (and it does use the Call Hierarchy in Eclipse, thanks Raedwald!)

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate I voted to close it.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the help, everyone.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.